# Use row from previous query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to set up an event in SQL for every first day of every month to grab some rows from a table and insert the results from that into another table.

What I'm using,

```
BEGIN
    SELECT posts.user_id,posts.id,posts.category,posts.date,posts.votes FROM posts ORDER BY posts.votes ASC;
    SET POST_ID = posts.id;
    SET USER_ID = posts.user_id;
    SET CATEGORY = posts.category;
    SET VOTES = posts.votes;
    INSERT INTO `winners` (`id`, `user_id`, `post_id`, `category`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, @USER_ID, @POST_ID, @CATEGORY, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y'));
END
```

Now I know this won't work (mainly because I tried it), but I was wanting to know of a way to set up this event without any user interaction at all.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you just want to use the `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax. If there's more to that, please elaborate (preferably with data samples and desired results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that Cronjobs would solve your problem. That will allow you to create (or use) a PHP Script that is run at preset intervals.

https://library.linode.com/linux-tools/utilities/cron

Comment: I'd like to do it this way. Is it not possible?

Comment: It is possible, you just need to set it up. For the first day of every month the format would be `0 0 1 * * user /path/to/file.php` - That link I gave you should walk you through setting it up. If you are on shared hosting, contact technical support to set it up for you.

Comment: I meant I'd like to do it via MySQL Events

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL 5.1.6, the [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) can be used to run an event without user interaction. Since you tagged phpMyAdmin, I'll also point out that phpMyAdmin has support for creating and editing events. From within the database, click the Event tab.